# Is English used for administration in Georgia?

Tags: language, georgia

I plan to move to Georgia (the country). I know English is not widely spoken in the country. I'll probably have to start learning Georgian. Do you know if people in administration services speak English? Are administrative papers written in Georgian or English?

Comment: Off-topic: Georgian is **hard**. I have a friend who speaks fluent Russian (and many other languages), worked in Georgia for years, but gave up learning the language. You can get around speaking Russian (but I understand learning Russian if you move to Georgia is weird).

Answer (score 2):

Englush isn't an official language of course, but you can definitely use it when communicating with the Public Service Hall, which is where you obtain and extend residence permits. There will always be someone speaking English.

Also, in general, surprisingly many people in Tbilisi do have some basic knowledge of English.

Answer (score 1):

As a Georgian, I can tell you that English is definitely taking over whereas Russian is becoming less and less popular. While overall average proficiency may not be that high, finding a person with a good command of English will not be a problem. English is spoken in most institutions in here. As for learning Georgian, it is one of the hardest languages to master, but in spite of that, if you are planning to move to Georgia on a permanent basis, you will have to learn the language at least at an intermediate level to establish  communication with the local population.